# Is returning a list a good programming practice?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i have a function that has to return 3 values, i haven't found a better way to do this other than returning a list. Is this code a good programming practice? And if not how to fix it.

Example function:

```
def func():
    #code
    return [a,b,c]
```

Main code:

```
   #code
   list = func()
   k = list[0]
   l = list[1]
   m = list[2]
```

Comment: You can directly return function as `return a,b,c` and unpack as `k,l,m = func()`

Comment: @Dexter that's just returning a tuple, and you can unpack *any* iterable.

Comment: Yes, returning lists is completely normal.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  I agree, list is completely fine. Tuple unpacking is just smoothing for the eyes :P

Answer (score 1):

You can pack/unpack directly in python:

```py
def func():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
    return a, b, c

k, l, m = func()
```

Comment: to be pedantic, `a, b, c` just creates a tuple, rather than a list, it's not more direct. But definitely, OP should use unpacking.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if we're being pedantic, the OP is mostly concerned with the best way of returning multiple values and it's only a coincidence that they tried a list first.